# Two identical inserts but for different tables - one works one doesn't

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I have two tables;

Table one

```
CREATE TABLE Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
    Fixture       INTEGER REFERENCES Fixture (ID),
    Player        INTEGER REFERENCES Player,
    Successful    INTEGER,
    Attempted     INTEGER,
    Was_Dribbled  INTEGER,
    Clearances    INTEGER,
    Interceptions INTEGER,
    Complete      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        Fixture,
        Player
    )
);
```

And Table Two

```
CREATE TABLE Player_Ratings (
    Fixture  INTEGER NOT NULL
                     UNIQUE,
    Player   INTEGER,
    Rating   INTEGER,
    Source   TEXT,
    Complete BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                     DEFAULT FALSE,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        Player
    )
    REFERENCES Player
);
```

I have the following code which works perfectly;

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player1
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player1 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player2
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player2 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player3
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player3 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player4
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player4 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player5
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player5 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player6
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player6 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player7
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player7 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player8
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player8 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player9
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player9 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player10
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player10 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player11
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player11 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub1
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub1 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub2
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub2 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub3
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub3 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub4
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub4 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub5
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub5 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub6
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub6 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Match_Stats_Tackles (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub7
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub7 IS NOT NULL;
```

And then I have the same code again but using `Player_Ratings` table

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player1
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player1 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player2
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player2 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player3
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player3 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player4
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player4 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player5
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player5 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player6
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player6 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player7
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player7 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player8
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player8 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player9
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player9 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player10
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player10 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Player11
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Player11 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub1
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub1 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub2
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub2 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub3
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub3 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub4
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub4 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub5
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub5 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub6
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub6 IS NOT NULL;

;

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Player_Ratings (
Fixture,
Player
)
SELECT LineUp.Fixture,
LineUp.Sub7
FROM LineUp
WHERE LineUp.Sub7 IS NOT NULL;

;
```

This second code stops after the first insert and only adds a few lines (10 when it should be c.180).

What am I doing wrong. The first code which works fine also works fine on 6 other tables just by changing the table name.

I have been searching google and using my SQL book for hours but can't get my head around it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a unique constraint on `Fixture` in Table 2 which I hadn't spotted where this should have been a composite key with Player